# installing elementaryOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So I am trying to install the new eOS from bootable USB stick. First I used LiLi as program to make my USB bootable. It doesn't support this OS so I ended up by not being able to boot it.

2nd try - with Unetbootin. I boot, but the installer of the OS crashes all the time. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest doing a fresh format of your usb to default settings and then trying "[universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)" by pendrivelinux.com, this supports elementaryOS and should hopefully work.

You should also check the integrity of your file you downloaded, it may have corrupted during download.

You can do this by downloading a simple portable program called [hashmyfiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hashmyfiles.zip).
Once that is downloaded, use hashmyfiles to open your .iso file.
Find the md5 and SHA1 checksums for your download by clicking the info button for the .iso you downloaded [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/?source=navbar)

[image]

Check the md5 and SHA1 calculated by hashmyfiles match the ones above. If they don't then that means your file has not downloaded correctly. Try download it again.